# localStorage value doesn't automatically updated

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```html
<div class="container">
                <h1>Your name...</h1>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
                <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Save">
</div>
```

I am new to localStorage, web storage in general. I made a very simple vanilla javascript project, "Say my name" app.

The project was about I input my name or anyone's name and when I clicked the "save" button, the name(input value) will be stored on localStorage.

I've tried setItem() feature and it worked, my input value was saved as localStorage value. But, when I typed new value and clicked the save button, the localStorage value didn't automatically updated. I had to refresh the localStorage every time I want to see the new value. Why is it like that?

Here is my simple code snippet:

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const btn = document.querySelector('#button');
const NAME_KEY = 'name';

const saveToLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(NAME_KEY, nameInput.value);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', saveToLocalStorage);
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <h1>Your name...</h1>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
                <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Save">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Where's the relevant markup?

Comment: "I had to refresh the localStorage every time I want to see the new value." You lost me there. Please explain what exactly you did to "refresh" (?) localStorage. Could it be you meant to say "refresh the _page_"?

Comment: Is your app also *using* the name from localstorage anywhere? You've only shown the code that writes it, but not the code that reads it.

Comment: I've made the code that reads it(display the value to the page), it worked perfectly fine for that part(shows the updated value). I didn't show the code here because I thought I want to highlight the problem for the not updating localStorage when there is new value, unless I refreshed the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
const btn = document.querySelector('#button');
const NAME_KEY = 'name';

const saveToLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(NAME_KEY, nameInput.value);
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(NAME_KEY);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', saveToLocalStorage);
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <h1>Your name...</h1>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
                <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Save">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is good. But you forgot to get data from localStorage to where you want to show.
I simply add one line { document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(NAME_KEY); } in your function to get data in "H1" Tag

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've written something similar to this(display the value to the page), and It worked. My real question/problem is why the value on the page updated automatically but not on the localStorage value? I have to refresh the localStorage every time I want to see the updated value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const btn = document.querySelector('#button');
const NAME_KEY = 'name';

const saveToLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(NAME_KEY, nameInput.value);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', saveToLocalStorage);
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <h1>Your name...</h1>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
                <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Save">
</div>
```

C